# Laravel api receive error 404 not found but I don't understand why

Tags: laravel

I don't know why, but I continue to receive 404 when I call my endpoints on postman
my routes:

```
Route::get('getlist', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@getList');
Route::post('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login');
Route::post('/register','App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register');
```

I don't know if it's relevant but I've done changes in my auth.php also

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'guards' => [
            'api' => [
                'driver' => 'jwt',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
        ],        
    ],
```

Obviously I've started my application with php artisan serve

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting from postman, add it to the question

Comment: Did you add the routes in `api.php` or `web.php`?

Comment: Undo your changes in `auth.php` The default will do. Transfer the routes to `api.php` if you have not done so. Then the url will be `url/api/getlist`

Answer (score 0):

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
],
```

Call endpoint from postman like this:

```
your_app_base_url/api/getlist
```

If you have any prefix like v1 etc:

```
 your_app_base_url/api/v1/getlist
```

Answer (score 0):

some problem may fixed by this command

> php artisan optimize

and try to check your route list with

> php artisan route:list

and make sure your route has shown